# Pyspark explode string to column with multiple lines

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data frame `df` in pysprak:

```
--name: string
--type: string
--con: string
```

The `con` column is something like below:

```
[{"count": "0", "sum": "100"}]
[{"count": "7", "sum": "10"}]
[{"count": "22", "sum": "223"}, {"count": "11", "sum": "75"}]
```

I am trying to explode `con` column combined with `name` and `type` to a new dataframe.

For `[{"count": "22", "sum": "223"}, {"count": "11", "sum": "75"}]`, I am trying to have 2 rows with same name and type but with different count and sum numbers

I am using:

```
df.withColumn("con", from_json(col("con"), schema)) 

schema = StructType([ StructField("count",StringType(),True), StructField("sum",StringType(),True)])
```

But didn't get the right number.

Comment: Can you give some complete sample data?

Comment: Your question is missing info. Could you also give the output of printSchema? And your full code, not just `withColunm("con", from_json(col("con"),schema))`

Comment: Added the missing part

Comment: @过过招 the sample data of con colunm is there, the other 2 cols are just regular string colunms

Comment: @Jerr567 Can you update about the below answer?

Answer (score 0):

From the sample data you gave, you should be able to parse the string column `con` into array of structs using this schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, ArrayType, StringType, StructType

schema = ArrayType(
    StructType([
        StructField("count", StringType(), True),
        StructField("sum", StringType(), True)
    ]),
    True
)
```

Then use `explode` and select the struct field or simply use [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#inline) function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [
    ("name1", "type1", '[{"count": "0", "sum": "100"}]'),
    ("name2", "type2", '[{"count": "7", "sum": "10"}]'),
    ("name3", "type3", '[{"count": "22", "sum": "223"}, {"count": "11", "sum": "75"}]'),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "type", "con"])

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "con",
    F.from_json(F.col("con"), schema)
).selectExpr(
    "name", "type", "inline(con)"
)

df1.show()
#+-----+-----+-----+---+
#| name| type|count|sum|
#+-----+-----+-----+---+
#|name1|type1|    0|100|
#|name2|type2|    7| 10|
#|name3|type3|   22|223|
#|name3|type3|   11| 75|
#+-----+-----+-----+---+
```

Comment: not working on my end

Comment: error u"\nextraneous input '<' expecting {'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'AS', 'ALL', 'DISTINCT', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'GROUPING', 'SETS', 'CUBE', 'ROLLUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'AT', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'NO', 'EXISTS', 'BET